# Char casting in java

Tags: java, casting

In my java code I have

```
result.append((num%b2)>=10?((char)('A'+((num%b2)-10))):(num%b2));
```

Where num and b2 are both integers. When num%b2 is greater than  or equal to 10

```
((char)('A'+((num%b2)-10)))
```

is appended to the stringbuilder result. However instead of appending a char it appends an int value with the ASCII number of the char I wanted to return. Why will it not return the char?

Comment: String.valueOf((char)('A' + ((num%b2)-10)));  OR  Character.toString((char)('A' + ((num%b2)-10)));  OR  (char)('A' + ((num%b2)-10)) + ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `(num%b2)` is an `int`.

The type of a conditional expression is the common type by which the two operands can be represented. So, if the "true" operand is a `char` but the "false" operand is an `int`, the result of `someCondition ? someChar : someInt` is an `int`.

It's a lot clearer if you just write it as a plain old if-else statement:

```
if (num%b2 >= 10) {
  result.append((char)('A'+((num%b2)-10)));
} else {
  result.append(num%b2);
}
```

Comment: Is that just a property of conditional expressions that whatever type the "false" value has the "true" value will be of the same type?

Comment: No: if you flipped the true and false operands around, it would be of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert it to string, and it will append it as string:

```
(char)('A'+((num%b2)-10)) + ""   // this will do nice and quick conversion
```